# ModalViewController Translucent Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I was using that piece of code to display a UIViewController as a modal with a translucent background (Working on IOS7 and lower).

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[navController presentViewController:myViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Now compiling with IOS8 show a modal with a black background.

Is there any solution ? (Without make an animated subView)
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this is the copy/paste issue, but you are presenting "myViewController", but setting modalPresentationStyle to navController.

Comment: It's the same, the navigationController has a modalPresentationStyle attribute that can be set to UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.
Setting it to the navController or UIViewController change nothing on IOS8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 8 and above, you can use 'UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext' for this purpose. From the UIViewController documentation:

> **UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext**
>
> A presentation style where the content is displayed over only the
>   parent view controller’s content. The views beneath the presented
>   content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation
>   finishes. So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen
>   with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.
>
> When presenting a view controller in a popover, this presentation
>   style is supported only if the transition style is
>   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical. Attempting to use a different
>   transition style triggers an exception. However, you may use other
>   transition styles (except the partial curl transition) if the parent
>   view controller is not in a popover.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

I was not aware that see-through modally presented view controllers were ever supported  prior to iOS 8 (and will be looking into that for my own use), but the above option definitely works in my testing in the new OS.

Note: Be sure to give your presented view controller a backgroundColor of clearColor.